# I need help writing a Junit 5 test for a Method

Tags: junit5

I am very new to Java, and I have been tasked with creating Junit5 tests for already written code. To start, I have the below method that I need to write a test for. I am unsure how to approach a test for this method.

`public static Double getFormattedDoubleValue(Number value){         return getFormattedDoubleValue(value, -1); }`

I tried the below test, and it passes, but I feel like I am testing the wrong thing here.

```
@Test
public void testDoubleString() {
    Double num = 41.1212121212;
    String expected = "41.12";
    String actual = String.format("%.2f", num);
    assertEquals(expected, actual, "Should return 41.12");}
```

Answer (score 0):

Writing tests are simpler than they are sometimes made out to be, all it is is just calling your code from a test class instead of a business logic class and making sure that you get the right output based on what you input.

Here is an excellent article that will take you from the very beginning of the process: [Baeldung: JUnit 5](https://www.baeldung.com/junit-5)

---

**Possible Sample Test**

As I'm not quite certain what the expectations of your method are, I am just going to pretend that your method should take a `Double`, and return that number minus one:

```java
@Test
void getFormattedDoubleValue_Test() {
    Double expected = 5.0L
    Double actual = getFormattedDoubleValue(expected + 1L)

    assertEquals(expected, actual)
}
```

Comment: Thank you  for trying to keep it simple for me and providing the link to the article. I will review it and I hope it helps me get started for my first test. If sample code for a test could be provide I would very much appreciate it. I think seeing the test for the method will help me better understand the approach after reviewing the article.

Comment: I've updated the answer with a quick and dirty example

Comment: Thanks for the input Jacob. Between the guide and the sample code, I am able to get started with my tests now. I appreciate your time and effort.